Firebase "DEFAULT" already initialized error
For those who are getting the firebase project DEFAULT already initialized error in flutter projects do below to fix it. Since the response available on stackoverflow was insufficient, I am creating this as another question. More refined. details from others are welcome in answers.

Delete Googleservices-info.plist from ios/runner directory
run flutterfire configure again
run flutter clean
run flutter pub get

change below in main.dart
bool _isFirebaseInitialized = false; // Track Firebase initialization

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Initialize Firebase only if it hasn't been initialized yet
  if (!_isFirebaseInitialized) {
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
      } else {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: const FirebaseOptions(
            apiKey: "your-api-key",
            appId: "your-android-app-id",
            messagingSenderId: "your-msg-sender-id",
            projectId: "your-project-id",
          ),
        );
      }
      _isFirebaseInitialized = true; // Set to true after successful initialization
    } catch (e) {
      print("Firebase initialization error: $e");
    }
  }

  // ... rest of the main function
}

Simply deleting the googleservice-info.plist doesn't work many a times as given in other response

It's great that you have found another, better answer to an existing problem, but please don't post it as a new question. Instead post it as an actual, alternative answer to that problem.
